# grpc .net-core app not visible from outside local

Tags: .net-core, grpc

I have grpc dotnet core app, dotnet core version 2.1.
App runs fine when executed on local maschine and accessed from that maschine. When I want to access it from other machine (althought firewall disabled, port opened) I can't access it. I think it is something to the code. I'm not dotnet developer but have some microservice legacy code:). Can it be that problem is in Grpc.Core Server class?

Please help out

Code:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO; 
using Grpc.Core;
```

...

```
static void Main()

{

const int port = 4000;

const string host = "localhost";

var cert = File.ReadAllText("cert.pem");

var key = File.ReadAllText("key.pem");

var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(cert, key);

var server = GetServer(port, host, keypair);

server.Start();

server.ShutdownTask.Wait();

}

private static Server GetServer(int port, string host, KeyCertificatePair keypair)

{

return new Server

{

Services = { SomeService.BindService(new SomeServiceImpl()) },

Ports = { new ServerPort(host, port, new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>

{

keypair

}))}

};

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code explicitly says `const string host = "localhost";` which means that it will only listen on the loopback interface (= not accessible from other machines). Use e.g. `"[::]"` or `"0.0.0.0"` to listen on all network interfaces.